# Investigate biggest objects (dominators) from a .NET Process memory dump

Tags: .net, debugging, memory-leaks, memory-dump

I've got a memory dump of .NET process which was created by DebugDiag on thrown System.OutOfMemoryException. Now I'm trying to figure out which objects are holding more memory than expected.

It's possible to open this dump with windbg+sos, perform simple analysis like shallow object size statistics and investigate particular objects, but that give me almost nothing. I'm interested in things like biggest dominators, dominator tree, retained memory held by particular objects and so on. Are there any tools for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `!objsize` command. See this interesting link about it: [I am getting OutOfMemoryExceptions. How can I troubleshoot this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/01/11/i-am-getting-outofmemoryexceptions-how-can-i-troubleshoot-this.aspx)

Comment: This is only part of a question. In fact objsize douesn't help me much, because in my case there are widely available objects which are also referenced from objects under my investigation and I don't want to take into account first ones during calculation of size for second ones.